# Python: Getting Errors when splitting rows of a file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I am going mad with an error Ill get. Reading a file from the internet and got so far that I clean up the content to have a lot of rows like this:
['38', ' Private', ' 193026', ' 11th', ' 7', ' Married-civ-spouse', ' Craft-repair', ' Husband', ' White', ' Male', ' 0', ' 0', ' 40', ' United-States', ' <=50K']

Now I want to split each segment of the row into a single data set. The '38' for example into "Age". 
The I see that I have int and string here. Further I want to get the strings somehow turned into int.

When I am doing the following:

```
for row in data_file:
    row = row.strip()
    row = row.split(",")

    try:
       row[0] = int (row [0])  #int(row(0))

    except ValueError as e:
        print (e)
    continue
```

I get the error:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

If I exchange the int (row [0])  to int(row(0)) 
Iam getting the error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Somehow I am lost…

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to make it an `int`?

Comment: I think so…. the first '38' I would like to have as an int. I would like to go through all the values in the mentioned line.

Comment: It seems that there are some rows that have an empty value (`''`) at the 0-th index. Check to make sure that your data is indeed complete. If it isn't, then you might have to catch the error and insert a default value, or ignore it, or basically handle it in some way

Comment: @AndiNeier Do the rows look like your example? Or is this just the list version of it?

Comment: Your parsing is incorrect. You need to remove the quotes from each element. However, if there is a comma in any quoted string, your results will be totally wrong. There are lots of CSV parsing examples for python available.

Comment: Yes - there are some lines where I have no data in the first place. I thought with the except ValueError as e: and continue statement I work around that…

Comment: Yes - if I do print(row) I get exactly the line above

Comment: @AndiNeier If you open the file, does it already have it in list form: meaning everything is in quotes within brackets? If it was already a list, then my example using `exec` would work. If you print the list `row`, then of course it is going to be in a list. The bottom line is that none of the answers were correct, because you did not even give an actual line example. Instead you gave us the goal of what to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to convert a string to `int`, make sure what's inside the string is a number. In your case, it seems for one of the rows you are parsing, you are getting '' (empty string) in the first position (`row[0]`), and it fails.

Work around in order to match integers just when it corresponds, for example the `continue` statement inside the exception block mighth be valid, but depends on what do you want to to in this case.

Comment: in addition to this, you can do dict(zip(myrows)) to make a key-value pair dictionary out from yout row splits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the example line is actually what you have above:

Right now, this is what your list looks like:

```
row = ["['38'", " ' Private'", " ' 193026'", " ' 11th'", " ' 7'", " ' Married-civ-spouse'", " ' Craft-repair'", " ' Husband'", " ' White'", " ' Male'", " ' 0'", " ' 0'", " ' 40'", " ' United-States'", " ' <=50K']"]
```

Basically, you also need to strip the `"["`s.

**Or, you can use exec**

`exec` executes a string as python code. So, this would be perfect for making your rows straight into lists.

```
for row in data_file:
    exec("row = "+row)
    #--------Your code----------
```

---

Each line looks like:

```
39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
```

You have been striping and splitting in the wrong order.

```
for row in data_file:
    row = row.split(",")
    for item in row:
        item = item.strip()
    try:
        row[0] = int(row[0])
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
    continue
```

Comment: If I include now exec("row = "+row) as mentioned I get the error
row = 39, State-gov, 77516, Bachelors, 13, Never-married, Adm-clerical, Not-in-family, White, Male, 2174, 0, 40, United-States, <=50K
                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

totally lost now